# How to send a Http Post request without json?

Tags: android, http, post, sms

I am building a project on vibration monitoring using arduino, where the acceleration data along 3 axis should be uploaded to server using http post request. Unfortunately the post request is not occuring here. The service is running, but the POST is not happening. The code I am using is here.

https://github.com/AgnivaDutta/Vibration_Monitor_App

The localhost.zip is my android project.

Can anyone point out what I am missing here.

Comment: post the relevant piece of code here. Nobody is going to set up new project environment to find what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register **Post_Data** Service in Manifest, Add

```
<service android:name=".Post_Data" />
```

Inside Application tag of your manifest file.